# Retrieve cookie and send it in subsequent POST requests

Tags: java, http, cookies

I want to read two numbers (randomly generated) from a website which are then used in order to compute a result and then submit the result using a POST request. To do so, I will also need to submit the cookie of that session so that the system is aware of the random numbers which have been produced in that particular session.

In order to read the numbers I am using `Jsoup`:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.connect("http://website.com/getNumbers").get().select("strong").text());
String[] numbers = document.text().split(" ");
String answer = methodThatComputesTheDesiredOutput(numbers);
```

Now I want to send a POST request that includes `answer` and `cookies` of that session. Here's a partially implemented POST request that includes only the one parameter (`answer`):

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/submitAnswer");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", answer);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
```

How can I obtain the cookie when reading the document and then use it as a parameter of the POST request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract cookies using jsoup in the following way:

```
    Response response = Jsoup.connect("http://website.com/getNumbers").execute();
    Map<String, String> cookies = response.cookies();
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(response.body());
```

Create a BasicCookieStore using the cookies extracted using jsoup. Create a HttpContext containing the cookie store and pass it while executing your next request.

```
    BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    for (Entry<String, String> cookieEntry : cookies.entrySet()) {
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(cookieEntry.getKey(), cookieEntry.getValue());
        cookie.setDomain(".example.com");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
    }


    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(HttpClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/submitAnswer");
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer", answer);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));

    httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I also pass the parameter `answer` to the request?

Comment: The same way as you were already doing. No change... I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: Cheers. Another question:         `cookie.setDomain(".example.com");
        cookie.setPath("/");` What values should I pass to these methods?

Comment: If you are making the call to `http://website.com/submitAnswer`, then use `cookie.setDomain(".website.com"); cookie.setPath("/");`

Answer (score 0):

Send your first request like below :-

```
Response res = Jsoup.connect("login Site URL")
        .method(Method.GET)
        .execute();
```

Now get the cookies and send new request with the cookies something like below :-

```
 CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
     for (String key : cookies.keySet()) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(key, cookies.get(key));
        cookieStore.addCookie((org.apache.http.cookie.Cookie) cookie);
    }
       HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setCookieStore(cookieStore);
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://website.com/submitAnswer");
        httpClient.execute(httpPost,context);
```